# Gstreamer splitmuxsink missing metadata/avi index

Tags: gstreamer

Gstreamer pipeline:

> ```
>  appsrc->queue->splitmuxsink (muxer=avimux)
> ```

In the appsrc basacally all input from a different pipeline (MJPEG frames) is being copied to the pipeline. The first 16 files created by splitmuxsink seems to be OK, all after that (until the last one if the pipeline is terminated correctly and not via the system loosing power) are reporting "broken or missing avi index" when played by VLC. Is there some setting causing this?

Edit: I ahave tried to use matroskamux instead of avimux. The resulted files have really messed-up timestamps (i think that the files have timestamps regarding the overall time, and not the time in the file - it is impossible to seek in the saved files in VLC since all the data are "after" the file ended.

I have multifilesink v1.14.2. It seems not to have some of the properties in documentation (e.g. reset-muxer) - i assume that adress this issue?

In case that is so, is there a relatevely simple way to update the plugin? It's running on the tinyrex module (armv7l, https://www.voipac.com/#iMX6-TRM-54842311) with linux (built from kernel 3.14). Is there an relatively easy way to update the gstreamer (there is no package manager on the tinyrex, afaik the gstremer was included during the compilation of the buildroot and sysroot - far beyond my scope)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation and examples of `splitmuxsink`:
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/multifile/splitmuxsink.html?gi-language=c

You are not supposed to mux the data youself, `splitmuxsink` will do this for you. You will just have to tell it what muxer to use.

So try something like:

> appsrc->queue->splitmuxsink muxer=avimux

Comment: Right, I guess my way of writing the pipeline is really wrong. in thruth the code is
`muxer = gst_element_factory_make ("avimux", "avimux");
 sink = gst_element_factory_make ("splitmuxsink", "sink");
 g_object_set (sink, "muxer", muxer, NULL);

`